# CodeIgniter styling dropdown options

Tags: php, codeigniter, background, drop-down-menu

So I am using the form helper to generate my forms. Up until now it worked just how I wanted it to work, but I stumbled upon the styling of the options of a form_dropdown.
Basically what I am doing right now is populating the dropdown from the database as can be seen in the following example;

```
// Set up the array for the colors.
$data_colors = array('0'=>'color');
foreach ($search_colors as $color)
{
    $data_colors[$color['color_id']] = $color['name'];
}
echo form_dropdown('color',$data_colors,'0');
```

Now, the database also got a row called 'hex'. What I am trying to do is setting the value of hex as background of the option.

Is that even possible or should I go back to manually writing the HTML code of the dropdown on this one?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That seems a little too advanced for the Form Helper's [form_dropdown()](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html) function. I can only see the option to give the entire drop down an ID or class and that wouldn't help since you want to style individual `option`s. So, yes, it's back to manually making the HTML code for now.